# New Computer Build - Boot display issues (always POSTs)

Tags: boot, memory, ssd, motherboard, bios

## Summary

I've recently built a new computer, I used [UK PC Part Picker](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/) to ensure all parts were compatible and to help with where to buy parts. I've built the machine now having a couple of issues.

### Build Parts

- CPU | I7 7740x
- Graphics | GTX 1070 G1
- PSU | 750W SilverStone Strider Gold S
- Motherboard | ASUS - ROG RAMPAGE VI APEX LGA2066 Motherboard
- Monitor | Tv 42" Samsung for now.
- CPU Cooler | Noctua NH-U9S, Premium CPU Cooler with NF-A9 92mm Fan (Brown)
- PC to Monitor Cable | HDMI
- Storage | 2 SSds SATA
- Memory | Corsair CMK32GX4M2A2400C16 Vengeance LPX 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4 2400 MHz
- Case | Silverstone Raven RV03B-WA Black Full Tower

`NOTE: More information available if needed.`

### Problem #1

The first issue is that the machine appears to boot up but there doesn't seem to be any affect on visually on the display but when I press the `Clear CMOS` button on the motherboard and restart the machine it boots into the BIOs where if I manually boot from the SSD I've got Windows installed on then the machine boots up correctly and I'm able to use as expected.

`Motherboard error code: 09`

#### Things I've tried

1. Replacing the motherboard Battery
2. Settings the boot up sequence in the correct order in the BIOs.
3. Disabled all detected boot-up drives accept the one that has Windows.
4. Removing the graphics and memory and putting them back in.
5. Gone over every component and checked everything is plugged in correctly.

I've searched and played around with it for hours and I've now rang out of ideas. I'm hoping someone can help resolve the issue as it's getting very frustrating very quickly having to manually boot from a specific drive just to be able to use it.

Comment: Have you installed Windows correctly in UEFI mode?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'm not sure there was a difference? How would I know? I plugged in my USB and booted from that and deleted all partitions and created a new one for my target drive then installed on there as I've always done in the past. Although when I attempt to press either `DELETE` or `F2` to enter the UEFI bios settings, it doesn't seem to allow me.

Comment: If you deleted everything and didn't created a new EFI partition then you definitely installed in Legacy mode. That's exactly where your problems start. Modern OSes that support UEFI mode **should always be installed in UEFI mode in an UEFI machine**. Not doing that opens the door to all sorts of problems with hardware initialization. And you don't need to create partitions to install, any modern installer - Windows or Linux distro - is capable of installing the OS in any unpartitioned drive.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Ah okay so does this mean I'll need to do a complete new format and reinstall windows but create a UEFI partition rather than a normal partition to be able to boot from it?

Comment: You need to have the drive as GPT first, then you don't even need to create partitions. Booting the installer in UEFI mode makes sure the proper EFI partitions will be created during installation. Better to disable any Legacy/CSM mode at UEFI settings to make sure the installer is booting in the correct mode.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Ah okay thanks for the help. I'll give this ago when I get home, I've never had this issue before now so has been very useful.